# Getting poll results from Facebook Graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I (if I can) get the results of a poll/question from Facebook graph?  Currently I get back something similar to what is below:

```
"data": [
      {
         "id": "12345_12345",
         "from": {
            "name": "My Company Name",
            "category": "Category",
            "id": "12345"
         },
         "story": "This is my question",
         "icon": "https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v1/yy/r/pz5wRf7MB0H.png",
         "privacy": {
            "description": "Public",
            "value": "EVERYONE"
         },
         "type": "question",
         "object_id": "12345",
         "application": {
            "name": "Questions",
            "id": "12345"
         },
         "created_time": "2012-04-25T12:23:03+0000",
         "updated_time": "2012-04-25T12:23:03+0000",
         "comments": {
            "count": 0
         }
      }
```

Can I get more information back about this question?  I'm currently using PHP + CURL to get the feed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, you have queried for the specific post (post-id:12345_12345)  : `https://graph.facebook.com/12345_12345` .

To get to the [question's data](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/question/) we have to query for the question id that is given in this post's data itself:

```
"type": "question",
"object_id": "12345",
```

from here we have the question's id, i.e `object_id:12345`. Using this id we can get the question's info, so query url is : `https://graph.facebook.com/12345`.

In the question's returned info, we'll also have the [options of the poll](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/question_option/), it'll be a field named `options`. Each option's info will be given within this field, and each option has a `votes` field, which will tell you the number of votes that option received. So you'll have the results of the poll.

Use the [graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), to test these things, before you code them. And do read the documentation links to know more about questions.

Answer (score 0):

In general the **metadata=1** GET parameter tells you if there is more related data available.